# Out of memory exception while compiling GWT project

Tags: java, gwt

As I didnt get any solution from previous similar question,I am raising this issue.
I have 8GB RAM,32 bit window 7 os,32 bit eclipse and 32 bit JVM. I used to compile my GWT project successfully.But after adding some uploading and mobile-related jars,I get this Out of memory exception while compiling this project.
I have tried to change the VM arguments,but got no success.Then I moved to 64 bit OS,64 bit eclipse,64 bit JVM, and tried to assign more Xmx parameter in the vm argument,but its not taking more than 1.5GB where as I have 8 GB RAM,Hence no success while compiling. Need Help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven to compile your gwt code :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
...
<configuration>
<extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048m</extraJvmArgs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, you may be using lots of servlets or GWT files.

- As far as you are using 64bit OS this should work with -Xmx 4096m. Try
  checking the path sometimes the JRE path will be pointing to x86 if
  so change to JRE installed on x64.
- If the VM arguments is not working for more than 2048m then probably
  it will be a issue with JRE(for x86) or OS architecture(x86).

Answer (score 0):

Changing to 64 bits was the right thing to do, but you have to make sure that Eclipse is using the right version of Java.

Check if you're pointing to the right version of Java in  Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE

Comment: Its pointing to right version of jre.I want to enhance the vm argument to 4gb.But its not taking.How can I do that?

Comment: In cmd what you get when you type : java -version

Answer (score 0):

> I have 8GB RAM,32 bit window

Fail. 32-bit operating system can technically only managed a maximum of 4 GB of RAM